# Configure email send using SMTP SSL/Port 465 on Python.(Redmail)

Tags: python, smtp, iredmail

```
from redmail import EmailSender
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL

email = EmailSender(
    host="smtp-es.securemail.pro",
    port=465,
    cls_smtp=SMTP_SSL,
    username= "xxxxxxxxx",
    password= "zzzzzzzzz" 
)

email.send(
    subject="An example email",
    sender="xxxxxxxxxxx",
    receivers=['you@example.com'],
    text="Hello!",
    html="<h1>Hello!</h1>"
)
```

I dont really know what to put on the EmailSender(), I tried the 5 parameters you see, little bit sure about the first three, completely no idea about the last two.

Comment: since you are using SSL-secured SMTP on port 465, your connection should already be encrypted, and you don't need to specify the starttls parameter (used for unencrypted SMTP with STARTTLS)

Comment: You're asking us what to use for username and password?

Comment: Generally for authenticated SMTP you would already have a relationship with the email relay, and they would tell you the username and password.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I establish the relationship. I´m relatively new on coding so...

Comment: Also, as a temporary solution I set my account via gmail, and then configure it, witch was easier because redmail library has gmail preconfigured.